# direct user to their respective subdomain after signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, apartment-gem

My user is able to sign up for the application and be directed to the appropriate subdomain that they type into the screen. I'd like them to be redirected back to the same subdomain when signing back in. I am not getting an error per say but when I am signing back in the system doesn't insert the subdomain in front of the url.

application_controller.rb

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   root_url(:subdomain => resource.subdomain) 
end 

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  root_url(subdomain: false)
end
```

routes.rb

```
class SubdomainPresent
  def self.matches?(request)
    subdomains = %w{ www admin }
    request.subdomain.present? && !subdomains.include?(request.subdomain)
  end
end

class SubdomainBlank
   def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank?
   end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :accounts
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'accounts', sessions: 'sessions' } 
get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'

constraints(SubdomainBlank) do
    root 'visitors#new'
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
    get 'services', to: 'pages#services'
    resources :contacts, only: :create
    resources :visitors, only: [:new, :create]
end 

constraints(SubdomainPresent) do
    root 'tasks#index', as: :subdomain_root
    resources :users do
      resource :profile
    end
    resources :tasks
    resources :deals
    resources :companies
end

end
```

Comment: What is the value of `resource_or_scope` in your first code block?

Comment: If you create a `RegistrationController` in your applictaion, you can use `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` or you can add it to your `ApplicationController` and tell `Devise` where to send user when they sign_in *(if you use `Devise gem`)*

Comment: Is it possibly because I am using an accounts controller to have my user sign up? rather than the standard registrations controller...